# Registering an invalid piece of data from a pattern

Tags: java, string, boolean

I need to use a six letter word and if it has a sequence of letter number letter number letter number, then it will be a valid piece of data. Otherwise, it will be considered invalid. The problem with my code is, it always runs it as valid. Here is my code:

```
        vstatus=false;

        char a=pcode.charAt(0);
        char b=pcode.charAt(1);
        char c=pcode.charAt(2);
        char d=pcode.charAt(3);
        char e=pcode.charAt(4);
        char f=pcode.charAt(5);

        if(!Character.isLetter(a)) vstatus=true;
        if(!Character.isDigit(b)) vstatus=true;
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) vstatus=true;
        if(!Character.isDigit(d)) vstatus=true;
        if(!Character.isLetter(e)) vstatus=true;
        if(!Character.isDigit(f)) vstatus=true;

        if (vstatus=true)
        {
            System.out.println(convertUpperCase(pcode)+" is a valid postal code");
        }
        if (vstatus=false) 
        {
            System.out.println(convertUpperCase(pcode)+" is not a valid postal code");
        }
```

Comment: A regex might make more sense here. You currently set `vstatus = true` if *any* of the pass. You need to check *all* conditions with an `&&`. It would seem more natural to assume valid, and if any validation *fails* you set `vstatus = false` (given the current structure).

Comment: Unrelated, but note that simple logging and/or stepping via debugger and/or "playing computer" w/ pencil and paper would be sufficient to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, even if one character is correct and all the others are wrong, you make it true. You need to confirm that all the characters are correct. Use `&&`.

```
String pcode = "i8i8i8";

char a=pcode.charAt(0);
char b=pcode.charAt(1);
char c=pcode.charAt(2);
char d=pcode.charAt(3);
char e=pcode.charAt(4);
char f=pcode.charAt(5);

if (Character.isLetter(a) && Character.isDigit(b) && Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isDigit(d) && Character.isLetter(e) && Character.isDigit(f)) {
    System.out.println("valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("not a valid postal code");
}
```

---

Or, in a loop:

```
String pcode = "i8i8i8";
boolean flag = true;

for (int i = 0; i < pcode.length(); i++) {
    if (!(i % 2 == 0 && Character.isLetter(pcode.charAt(i)) || Character
        .isDigit(pcode.charAt(i)))) {
        flag = false;
    }
}

if (flag) { System.out.println("valid"); } 
else { System.out.println("not valid"); }
```

---

Ideally, extract the code into a method:

```
static boolean isPcodeValid(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!(i % 2 == 0 && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) || Character
            .isDigit(s.charAt(i)))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Or, use some Java8+ features:

```
static boolean isPcodeValid(String s) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
        .allMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0 && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) || Character
            .isDigit(s.charAt(i)));
}
```

---

Finally,

You may use this regex:

```
String r = [A-Za-z][\d][A-Za-z][\d][A-Za-z][\d]
if (pcode.matches(r)) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

5 different ways, choose the one that suits you the best.

Answer (score 0):

I gues this would be shorter code for your problem:

```
    String pcode = "aza2a3";
    String regex = "[A-Za-z]{1}[\\d]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[\\d]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[\\d]{1}";
    boolean matches = pcode.matches(regex);
    System.out.println(matches);
```

matches is true if your string is in form that you need and false if i does not match your required string